# Make a printable report in php

Tags: php, database

I have work with vb 6.0 in my college activities before and make reports using active report 2.0 or crystal report...my question is how to make report in php and print data in my database just like in vb6.0? Can anyone provide me some sample program that print data in database so that i can use it as a guide or sample code?? I'm still learning php though.

Comment: There aren't any interactive report generators in php, and very few javascript assisted reports that print/export to multiple formats.  PDF generation is your best bet, but it will be static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also the problem I faced during my college days.
What I used back then was [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Good luck!